# SAS SQL: How to merge overlapping dates

Tags: sas, overlap

I'm trying to merge the dates if they overlap.
For example,

current data looks like,

```
ID  START     END 
223 20130101  20130201
223 20130104  20130109
223 20130120  20130320
223 20130430  20130930
110 19981219  20010412
110 20000901  20010206
110 20000926  20010306
110 20001002  20010423
110 20001218  20010306
110 20001218  20010306
```

the result I need is,

```
ID  START     END 
223 20130101  20130320
223 20130430  20130930
110 19981219  20010412
```

I looked up questions of this type, but could not make executable query fit to my data..
I could not even understand the codes, any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: This is much easier to do in the data step than in SQL.  Any particular reason why you want to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 4):

The data step solution to this is fairly simple.  This is a general form; you may need to adjust this for your specific data.

```
data have;
informat start end YYMMDD8.;
format start end DATE9.;
input ID  START     END;
datalines;
223 20130101  20130201
223 20130104  20130109
223 20130120  20130320
223 20130430  20130930
110 19981219  20010412
110 20000901  20010206
110 20000926  20010306
110 20001002  20010423
110 20001218  20010306
110 20001218  20010306
;;;;
run;
proc sort data=have;
by id start end;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id start end;
retain curstart curend;
format curstart curend DATE9.;
if first.id then do;   *clear the retained variables for first record of new id;
    curend=.;
    curstart=.;
end;
if start > curend then do;   *if there is a gap, or it is the first record of a new id;
    if not (first.id) then output;
    curstart=start;
    curend=end;
end;
else if end > curend then do;  *update the current period end;
    curend=end;
end;
if last.id then output;  *output the final record for each ID;
run;
```

Comment: thanks i tried your code and it runs well, but the result only fetches the last interval for any id.

Comment: Then you have some other issue.  I ran the above code and got the desired 2 rows for the first ID and 1 for the second.